# How can I tell the size of a file from a kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel

How can I tell the size of a file from a kernel module?

I know about `vfs_llseek()` but I also need an equivalent function to `ftell()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the size of a file in the linux kernel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966071/how-do-you-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-the-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could tyry to use vfs_llseek with a offset of 0 and whence of SEEK_END: it will go to the end and return the file position (which will be the end of the file)

Likewise for the current position, toy would use offset 0, SEEK_CUR, to return the current position.